# HTML Tag Displayed in the SMS message SF marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have a problem with the Concat function in marketing cloud SMS and the result.
The message is concatened but i have as a result a HTML Tag at the beginig of the message .

The message is :

```
%%[
var @msg,@msg1,@msg2,@msg3,@msg4
if @Language__pc=="FR"
then 
set @msg1 = ConCat('Vos informations ......',' ',@HotelName)
set @msg2 = ConCat('Réservation N :',' ',@Booking_Number)
set @msg3 = ConCat('Chambre N :',' ',@RoomNumber)
set @msg4 = ConCat('Code d accès :',' ',@RoomCode)


set @msg =ConCat(@msg1,@msg2,@msg3,@msg4)


ELSE 

SET @msg="test sms EN"

endif

]%% 

%%=v(@msg)=%%
```

and the result begin with this HTML Tag :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"></td></tr></table>
```

could you help me to understand the issue?

Thanks

Comment: is this in the Message body in mobile studio? or in a content block?

Comment: That HTML gets wrapped around HTML and Free Form content block type. Place that code using the Snippet content block type - it'll then render exactly what your output will be.

Comment: @EazyE yes it's in mobile studio

Comment: @EduardoArias it's on Mobile Studio, how can i create a code snipet within a message in Mobile message?